# Conflict in namespace in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

If my namespace is

Cytel.GlobalSettings.ChartSetting

and
I have a static class ChartSetting

packed in dll.

then when I use ChartSetting class in other project it shows red color with Chartsetting class's method and public members are not shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is interpreting your reference to `ChartSetting` as a reference to the namespace. You should use the fully qualified name of the `ChartSetting` static class. If it has an empty namespace, then you will need to use the `global` qualifier thus:

```
global::ChartSetting
```

You can also specify an alias to this class:

```
using MyAlias = global::ChartSetting;
```